# How do I return a list of cell values in Excel based on two criteria?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a data set of Dates, Names, and Organization IDs:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+
|   Date    |  Name  | Org ID |
+-----------+--------+--------+
| 4/6/2020  | John D | 113808 |
| 4/6/2020  | John D | 113743 |
| 4/6/2020  | John D | 113984 |
| 4/6/2020  | Jane S | 933445 |
| 4/6/2020  | Jane S | 933455 |
| 4/6/2020  | Jane S | 933467 |
| 4/13/2020 | John D | 113927 |
| 4/13/2020 | John D | 103266 |
| 4/13/2020 | John D | 112352 |
+-----------+--------+--------+
```

I'm trying to come up with a formula that will return an Org ID for a specific person on a specific date and will continue returning the next Org ID in the list for that person as the code is copied down the column. I'm currently using a Slicer connected to the 'Name' field that will update my list according to the name I'm choosing. So if I select John D on the Slicer, I'm expecting the following output:

```
+-----------+--------+
|   Date    | Org ID |
+-----------+--------+
| 4/6/2020  | 113808 |
| 4/6/2020  | 113743 |
| 4/6/2020  | 113984 |
| 4/13/2020 | 113927 |
| 4/13/2020 | 103266 |
| 4/13/2020 | 112352 | 
+-----------+--------+
```

This is the formula I'm currently using:

```
=INDEX('Org Summary'!$C:$C,SMALL(IF('Org Summary'!$E:$E='Pivot '!$AH$57,ROW('Org Summary'!$E:$E)-ROW(INDEX('Org Summary'!$E:$E,1,1))+1),Q9))
```

- Org Summary C = Org ID List
- Org Summary E = Name List
- Pivot Table AH57 = Pivot Table with 'Name' as a filter.
- Q9 = Refers to the 'Number' field below, I had to use a number placeholder so that I wouldn't get duplicates when the formula was copied to the next cell.

  ```
    Date     Number   Org ID
  4/6/2020     1      113808   <-- The =index formula above returns this. Number 1 = Q9 
               2      113743
               3      113984
  4/13/2020    4      113927
               5      103266
               6      112352
  ```

My formula currently returns the list of IDs associated with the Name selected in the Slicer and the Number field ensures that I don't have duplicates but date is not factored into the equation. I would like to return this list of Org IDs based on the Name in the Slicer and the dates in the Date List.

Below is the formula I made when I tried nesting an AND statement:

```
=INDEX('Org Summary'!$C:$C,SMALL(IF(AND('Org Summary'!$E:$E='Pivot '!$AH$57, 'Org Summary'!B:B="4/6/2020"),ROW('Org Summary'!$E:$E)-ROW(INDEX('Org Summary'!$E:$E,1,1))+1),Q9))
```

- Org Summary B = Date List

When I attempted the formula with the AND statement, I received a #SPILL! error.

Is there a more efficient formula I could use to return my list of Org IDs based on Name and Date?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2016.